# Service in Angular Resolve $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use `resolve` and inject it a `factory` and then print the data returned by the resolve in a `controller`.

Basically the code looks like pretty much :

```
 angular
        .module('appRouter',['ui.router'])
        .controller('routerCtrl',function(resolveData){
            console.log(resolveData);

        })
        .factory('repoService',function($http){
            var API = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
            return {
                getResolveData : function($http){
                    return $http.get(API);
                }
             }
        })
        .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
            $stateProvider
                .state('settings.profile',{
                    url:'/profile',
                    templateUrl:'templates/profile.html'
                })
                .state('settings.account',{
                    url:'/account',
                    templateUrl:'templates/account.html',
                    controller:'routerCtrl',
                    controllerAs:'vm',
                    resolve:{
                        resolveData : function(repoService){
                            return repoService.getResolveData().then(function(response){
                                return response.data;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/settings/profile');  

        });
```

But the code does not work . `No error in console but the routing to settings/account does not work . And nothing is printed on the console.`

**BUT**

The below code works pretty fine if we do it without injecting a service.

```
            .state('settings.account',{
                url:'/account',
                templateUrl:'templates/account.html',
                controller:'routerCtrl',
                controllerAs:'vm',
                resolve:{
                    resolveData : function(){
                         var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
                         return $http.get(root+'/posts/1').then(function(response){

                             return response.data;
                         });
                    }
                }
            });
```

I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong ? Please explain.

Comment: `getResolveData : function($http){` remove $http it's already defined on class level.

Comment: @Walfrat Lovely. Thanks.